# how to select li of ul in selenium webdriver using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am new to selenium. I am working on selenium webdriver. i want to select a value from the li of ul. I need to select a country from list items.

Here is the HTML code;

```
<div class="select-wrapper initialized">
<span class="caret">▼</span>
<input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-45625784-059c-3523-a00e-3ad824fad64a" value="-- Select --">

<ul id="select-options-45625784-059c-3523-a00e-3ad824fad64a" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown ">

<li class=""><span>-- Select --</span>

</li><li class=""><span>Afghanistan</span></li>
</li><li class=""><span>Canada</span></li>

</ul>

<select ng-if="!form.translate" id="countryCode" materializecss-select="" ng-model="model['countryCode']" ng-model-options="form.ngModelOptions" ng-disabled="form.readonly" sf-changed="form" class="initialized" schema-validate="form" ng-options="item.value as item.name group by item.group for item in form.titleMap" name="countryCode">

<option label="-- Select --" value="string:" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>

<option label="Afghanistan" value="string:AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option label="Canada" value="string:AF">Canada</option>

</select>

</div>
```

Here is my selectCountry function.

```
By countryInput = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"countryCode_inputfileddiv\"]/div/input");

public void selectCountry() {
        WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(countryInput);
        dropdown.click();

        List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.id("select-options-b9a0d236-4008-830c-5319-9405f74b872f"));

        for (WebElement option : options) {
            String valueToSelect = option.getText().trim();
            System.out.println(valueToSelect);
            if (valueToSelect.equals("Canada")) {
                continue;
            }

            option.click();
        }

    }
```

How to click the drop down?

I tried with the above example lines but am getting error such as

> Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration

Comment: Can you share the URL of the application if it can be shared to public?

Comment: Please add the screenshot of the DOM of that element. you paste the DOM attributes but I didn't understand the hirarchy.

Comment: Sorry i can not share the application.

Comment: can you ignore the select option code part.

Answer (score 1):

I see a `<select>` node in the HTML. You can use selenium's `Select` class to handle/choose dropdown values. Refer the code below:

```
Select drpCountry = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("countryCode")));
drpCountry.selectByVisibleText("Canada");
```

Imports required:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
```

Comment: I tried this one but getting this error. org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated. I think Items are selected from ul list items.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void selectCountry() {
        WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("countryCode"));
        Select select=new Select(dropdown);
        select.selectByVisibleText("Afghanistan");
    }

if we want to select Canada just pass Canada in selectByVisibleText() method
```